# ERROR: rpm-native-1_4.14.1-r0 do_configure: no configure script found at ../git

Tags: yocto

Into a yocto build, with poky in sumo branch for a wandboard. Getting errors in some of the native packages as follows

```
ERROR: rpm-native-1_4.14.1-r0 do_configure: no configure script found at ../git
/configure
```

and also

```
ERROR: glib-2.0-native-1_2.54.3-r0 do_configure: no configure script found at ../glib-2.54.3
/configure
```

Unable to trace the error .

Comment: Not sure the root cause. Maybe caused by share state? Please check whether `bitbake rpm-native -c cleanall && bitbake rpm-native` work.

Answer (score 1):

Changing `TERM` from `xterm-256color` to for example `linux` solved this for me.

```
TERM=linux bitbake image
```

Found solution on a Chinese site, http://www.soolco.com/post/25669_1_1.html

Comment: Worked for me. Spent the whole day looking for this. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

This error is raised from **autotools.bbclass**. There is part which replace direct path to **configure** script with relative one:

`cfgscript=python3 -c "import os; print(os.path.relpath(os.path.dirname('${CONFIGURE_SCRIPT}'), '.'))"/$cfgscript_name`

For some reason a newline is inserted into path and that is why this error is reported.
I tried to modify this script but still had this problem.

Finally I found that problem is caused (at least in my case) by fact that I have newer python3 version on my PC.

I was worked on Lubuntu 18.04 with python3 3.6.9

I didn't try to downgrade python3 only but to avoid other dependencies I've just downgraded whole Lubuntu to 16.04 with pyhon3 3.5.2 and now everything works properly.